# Retrofit Url Changing when i am giving the query

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Hi friends need help in the retrofit i am beginner in the using retrofit please help me out i need the url to be like this

**http://54.202.3.127/parallel_space/paralleljson.php?action=aboutus&id=1**

if i set the using

```
**@GET("paralleljson.php?action={terms}")
    Call<Terms_UserGuide_About> termsuserguide(@Path("terms") String terms,@Query("id")String id);**
```

its giving me this error

URL query string "action={terms}/" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

if i replace path with query then the url is changing like this

```
@GET("paralleljson.php?action=")
    Call<Terms_UserGuide_About> termsuserguide(@Query("terms") String terms,@Query("id")String id);
```

**http://54.202.3.127/parallel_space/paralleljson.php?action=&terms=aboutus&id=1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@GET("paralleljson.php")
Call<Terms_UserGuide_About> termsuserguide(@Query("action") String terms,@Query("id")String id);
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks it worked then where will be using the path sir?

Comment: Thank u sir its helped me alot